# How to limit domain results with criteria

Tags: grails, groovy

I am new to grails and I have a question about limiting a query result:
domain User:

```
class User {    
    String login
    String password
    String fname
    String lname
    String role = "user"    

    static constraints = {
        login    (size:5..15, blank:false, unique:true, matches:"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
        password (size:5..15, blank:false)
        fname    (blank:false)
        lname    (blank:false)
        role     (inList:["user", "admin"])
    }

    String toString(){
        fname & " " & lname
    }

    static mapping = {
        cache true

        columns {
            fname     type:'text'
            lname     type: 'text'
            password  type:'text'
            login     type:'text'
        }   
    }
}
```

my GSP page snippet that displays the results:

```
<g:each in="${userInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInstance">
  <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'odd' : 'even'}">
    <td><g:link action="show" id="${userInstance.id}">
      ${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field:   "id")}</g:link></td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "login")}</td>
    <td>****</td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "fname")}</td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "lname")}</td>
    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "role")}</td>
  </tr>
</g:each>
```

I call the controller with this code, in separate gsp view:

```
<g:link class="users" controller="user" params="[sort:'fname',order:'desc']" action="">Manager Users</g:link>
```

My question is, how do I call the domain and display the results according to the following criteria:  first, if the Role is admin, display everything.  If the role is not admin, only display the results of certain login value (ie, just show the results where the login = the current user)

Thanks for your help!
jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `users` controller `index` action such as:

```
def index = {
    if (isAdmin()) {
        [ userInstanceList: User.list(params) ]
    } else {
        [ userInstanceList: User.findAllByLogin(currentUser.login) ]
    }
}
```

Of course you need to define `isAdmin()` and `currentUser`, but those depend on your security implementation. If using `spring-security-core` plugin, you can use:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils

class UsersController {

    def springSecurityService

    def index = {
        if (SpringSecurityUtils.ifAllGranted(['ROLE_ADMIN'])) {
            [ userInstanceList: User.list(params) ]
        } else {
            [ userInstanceList: User.findAllByLogin(springSecurityService.currentUser.login) ]
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```

See the section on [helper classes](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html) in the [spring-security-core](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/index.html) plugin documentation for more info.

Comment: Great!  switching to the security plugin really helped

Answer (score 5):

A best & full-fledge authentication solution is SpringSecurity plugin as Gustavo propose, but I assume that you just want a simple criteria example. In controller, you can set your `userInstanceList` as following:

```
def currentUser = User.get(1); // put your current user here
def c = User.createCriteria()
def userInstanceList = c.list {
    or {
        and {
                  ne("role","admin")
                  eq("login",currentUser.login)
                }
        eq("role", "admin")
    }
    maxResults(10)
    order("login", "asc")
}
```

Details about criteria can be found [here](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I switched to the security plugin as you both suggested and it made things easier. thanks!